# Python Access object content

Tags: python, variables, object

I wonder how to access the content of the following object with python:

```
<Quota: (injected_file_content_bytes, 10240)>
```

I already tried to access the content of my variable called **myQuota** with **myQuota[0]** and **myQuota.injected_file_content_bytes**. None of them worked.

Comment: Where did that object come from?  To know how to use it, you need to know what it is or have some kind of documentation for it.

Comment: It comes from an API. Does it matter where it comes from?

Comment: Of course it matters. That string representation gives you no details about how to access the data. The documentation would.

Comment: Yes, because where it comes from is where you should look for documentation on how to use it.  If someone showed you a picture of a strange machine and said "How do I use this?" you wouldn't be able to answer without knowing something about what it's for, where it came from, instructions, etc.  There's no magical recipe for how to use any object in Python; you have to have some kind of documentation.

Comment: Is it OpenStack-related by any chance?

Comment: @s16h Yes, it is, thats why it is so hard to get any kind of documentation.

Comment: Did you try `dir(myQuota)` to see what is available? Oh. I see someone already answered that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `dir(myQuota)` to see what attributes the object has. Then take it from there (or edit your question to include it) and consider what you can do with it. Alternatively, there must be some documentation explaining what this object contains.

What does the [built-in `dir` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir) do?

> Without arguments, return the list of names in the current local
>   scope. With an argument, attempt to return a list of valid attributes
>   for that object.

Comment: Hi, thanks! The dir function returned me the object. Now i can access the object with the name and limit attributes (:.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `__dict__`

`myQuota.__dict` will give you the object attributes in form of key value pairs